# Convert negative and positive numbers to positive values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a dynamic value. Sometimes it comes with positive value and sometimes with negative value. But I always need a positive value. Is there any way to convert all negative or positive values to positive values?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [**Math.abs()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) :

```
var x = -25;
alert(Math.abs(x)); //it will alert 25
```

Here are some test cases from the documentation:

```
Math.abs('-10');     // 10
Math.abs(-20);       // 20
Math.abs(null);     // 0
Math.abs("string"); // NaN
Math.abs();         // NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Math.abs(x) for getting positive value as output. Here 'x' can be any positive or negative value

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully functional example in addition to the answer above.

```
$('#amount').change(function() {
    var amount = $(this).val();
    var positive_number = Math.abs(amount);
    if (positive_number > 0) {
        $('#amount').val(positive_number);
    }
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

By using Math.abs(value) we will be able to do wonder.

**Make a number positive**

```
let x =  12;
let y = -12;
let resultx =  Math.abs(x); //  12
let resulty =  Math.abs(y); //  12
```

**Make a number negative**

```
let x =  12;
let y = -12;
let resultx = -Math.abs(x); // -12
let resulty = -Math.abs(y); // -12
```

**Inverting a number**

```
let x =  12;
let y = -12;
let resultx = -(x);         // -12
let resulty = -(y);         //  12
```